# How to create a time chart display in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following information dataframe that logs quiz attempts in a given alloted period and also how long each takes. Each student is given a 25 minute period to complete a test and they can complete as many as they want.

my data is:

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
data = [['tom', 1,1,1,'0:00','10:26']
        ,['tom', 1,1,2,'15:30','18:50']
        ,['tom', 1,2,1,'2:00','9:15']
        ,['tom', 1,2,2,'13:10','22:40']
        ,['tom', 2,1,1,'5:00','22:15']
        ,['tom', 2,2,1,'0:00','13:40']]

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Day','AllottedPeriod','AttemptNo','StartTime','EndTime']) 
df
```

[image]

And what I am trying to do is create a simple visual something like the following to visualise diffences in attempt timings of students. I'm not quite sure how to go about it but does anyone have any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks very much!

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: How do you determine how much time was allotted? Is there a column with the following values (5,10,15,20,25)

Comment: Hi @kait. It’s always 25 minutes so I could add in a column that has 25 in it?

Comment: Okay, couple questions: would the columns  be: name, day, attempt 1, attempt 2? what is determining the color in the table you posted: Red if Allotted period 2 took longer than Allotted period 1? For days that there were multiple attempts for the same allotted period, which one do you want to keep?

Comment: Yes hoping for those to be the column names. I'm simply wanting to highlight Green for when the test is taken during the 25min period and red when the a test isnt taken (ie student is resting). So you would see that in day 1 `tom` did a test from 0 to 10:26 and then another from 15:30 to 18:50 so there are two green sections in the `Allotted Period 1`. Does that make sense? I should mention the coloured tabel is a rough estimate (as thats what im trying to figure out how to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assumptions:

Let me know if I misunderstood something (for example, if you only want to include the first attempt)

- There is a row for each combination of Name, Day, AllottedPeriod, and AttemptNo.

Time ranges are grouped by 5 minutes.

- `05 == 1` if test was active anytime between 00:00 & 5:00
- `10 == 1` if test was active anytime between 05:00 & 10:00
- `15 == 1` if test was active anytime between 10:00 & 15:00
- `20 == 1` if test was active anytime between 15:00 & 20:00
- `25 == 1` if test was active anytime between 20:00 & 25:00

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    ['tom', 1, 1, 1, '0:00', '10:26'],
    ['tom', 1, 1, 2, '15:30', '18:50'],
    ['tom', 1, 2, 1, '2:00', '9:15'],
    ['tom', 1, 2, 2, '13:10', '22:40'],
    ['tom', 2, 1, 1, '5:00', '22:15'],
    ['tom', 2, 2, 1, '0:00', '13:40']
]
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['Name',
             'Day',
             'AllottedPeriod',
             'AttemptNo',
             'StartTime',
             'EndTime'],
    data=data,
)


def parse_time_periods(x):
    start_minute, start_second = x['StartTime'].split(':')
    end_minute, end_second = x['EndTime'].split(':')
    # calculate the start and end time in seconds
    start = (int(start_minute) * 60) + int(start_second)
    end = (int(end_minute) * 60) + int(end_second)
    test_range = range(start, end)
    for i in range(5, 26, 5):
        # create range to check for intercection with testing time
        time_range = range((i - 5) * 60, i * 60)
        # create variables to indicate if there is overlap between
        # test time and minute range. For example, if a test was active
        # between minute 10 and minute 15, column `15` will be 1
        if len(set(test_range).intersection(time_range)) > 0:
            x[f'{i:02}'] = 1
    return x


df = df.apply(lambda x: parse_time_periods(x), axis=1).fillna(0)

stacked_df = df.groupby(
    by=['Name', 'Day', 'AttemptNo', 'AllottedPeriod']
).agg(max).unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1)

display(
    stacked_df
    .style
    .format(formatter='{:0,.0f}', subset=stacked_df.select_dtypes('float').columns)
    .background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn')
)
```

### End result

[image]

If you want to drop the `StartTime` and `EndTime` columns, you can modify the code like this

```
stacked_df = df.drop(columns=['StartTime', 'EndTime']).groupby(
    by=['Name', 'Day', 'AttemptNo', 'AllottedPeriod']
).agg(max).unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1)

display(
    stacked_df
    .style
    .format(formatter='{:0,.0f}', subset=stacked_df.select_dtypes('float').columns)
    .background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn')
)
```

[image]

If you wanted to change the time ranges, e.g. grouping by 1 minute, not 5, you could modify the code like this:

```
def parse_time_periods(x):
    start_minute, start_second = x['StartTime'].split(':')
    end_minute, end_second = x['EndTime'].split(':')
    # calculate the start and end time in seconds
    start = (int(start_minute) * 60) + int(start_second)
    end = (int(end_minute) * 60) + int(end_second)
    test_range = range(start, end)
    for i in range(1, 26, 1):
        # create range to check for intercection with testing time
        time_range = range((i - 1) * 60, i * 60)
        if len(set(test_range).intersection(time_range)) > 0:
            x[f'{i:02}'] = 1
    return x
```

If you wanted to drop the second attempt, you could do something like this:

```
df = df[df.AttemptNo == 1].drop(columns=['AttemptNo'])
stacked_df = df.groupby(
    by=['Name', 'Day', 'AllottedPeriod']
).agg(max).unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1)

display(
    stacked_df
    .style
    .format(formatter='{:0,.0f}', subset=stacked_df.select_dtypes('float').columns)
    .background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn')
)
```

If you wanted to include both attempts, you can use this:

```
stacked_df = df.drop(columns=['StartTime', 'EndTime','AttemptNo']).groupby(
    by=['Name', 'Day', 'AllottedPeriod']
).agg(sum).unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1)

display(
    stacked_df
    .style
    .format(formatter='{:0,.0f}', subset=stacked_df.select_dtypes('float').columns)
    .background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn',axis=1)
)
```

Comment: thanks very much @Kait. This looks great. I'll be testing it out tomorrow so will let you know how it goes. If i wanted to strecth out the time framed from 5min blocks to 1min blocks then i can just adjust the `for i in range(5, 26, 5)` line?

Comment: and also looking at your last picture: if i wanted to just have 1 line per day, would i just delete out `AttemptNo` or will i need to somehow combine the two `AttemptNo` lines for `Day 1` ?

Comment: I updated my answer to include code that you can use to group by 1 minute and for dropping attempt 2.

Comment: This is great and all works perfectly! Thanks @kait. Not sure i was clear enough with my last question. The final thing i would like to do is have just 1 line per day - including both attempts (instead of dropping the second attempt like you have in the last bit of code). Can that be done?

Comment: Yes, it can. I just added that to my answer

Comment: hi @kait. The next thing i would like to do is put this into a plot as opposed to just displaying in Jupyter. I can seem to reorder the `stacked_df` to a pivot table to then use something like a heatmap. Would you have any resources to help with that? thanks!

Comment: A pivot in Excel?

Comment: All good i worked out how to do in python and then send to a sns.heatmap. Thanks again!